# Browser cache problems with webpack chunks and vue.js components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, browser-cache, laravel-mix

**The Problem**

I have a problem with cached Vue.js components and I can't reproduce this problem on my devices but every client-side update we get users complains about broken interfaces and only clearing browser cache helps.

I use Laravel + Vue.js and it's multipage app.

**Strategy**

All components described in one file which included in app.js and it looks like this:

```
Vue.component('task-feed', () => import('./components/task/task-feed'/* webpackChunkName: "/js/components/task-feed" */));
Vue.component('task-item', () => import('./components/task/task-item'/* webpackChunkName: "/js/components/task-item" */));
```

There are vue.js async components.

And then i have configured webpack.mix like this:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ChunkManifestPlugin = require('chunk-manifest-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackChunkHash = require('webpack-chunk-hash');
mix.disableNotifications();
let config = {
    watchOptions: {
        ignored: /node_modules/
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue$': mix.inProduction() ? 'vue/dist/vue.runtime.min.js' : 'vue/dist/vue.runtime.js',
        }
    },
    output: {
        chunkFilename: mix.inProduction() ? '[name].[chunkhash].js' : '[name].js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
        new WebpackChunkHash(),
        new ChunkManifestPlugin({
            filename: '/js/chunk-manifest.json',
            manifestVariable: 'webpackManifest',
            inlineManifest: true,
        }),
    ],
};

mix.webpackConfig(config);
```

I'm using ChunkManifestPlugin here, that plugin creates chunk-manifest.json and i load it in the main layout like this:

```
window.webpackManifest = JSON.parse(@json(file_get_contents(public_path('/js/chunk-manifest.json'))));
```

**Questions**

What could be wrong here? Can anyone suggest the way to solve this?

Comment: Pls describe the complaints ;) What goes wrong?

Comment: We get users complains about broken interfaces and only clearing browser cache helps.

Comment: Assuming you did use mix in your blade file?  i.e. {{ mix('js/manifest.js') }} {{ mix('js/vendor.js') }} {{ mix('js/app.js') }} to prevent cache of main files.

Comment: Since you're using laravel and mix, if you haven't, I would suggest doing `mix.extract` and use `mix` helper in blade to version cache main files (manifest,vendor,app) for browser.  Then just use `WebpackChunkHash` to handle chunk file version and caching for browser.

Comment: Yes we use mix function for any resource file and extraction vendor file too. The problem not in main files but in chunk files.

Comment: As I mentioned, all you need is `WebpackChunkHash`.  I think your issue is with `ChunkManifestPlugin`, you do not need it.  I think that plugin has issue, no updates has been published for a year (see queued github issue not yet published).  It is also describe as "allows to actually leverage long-term caching," which is not what you want here.

Comment: @Vaulverin were you able to sort out your caching issues? We're experiencing the same issues when we deploy an update. Client has issues until they clear their cache. We're also using Laravel, Vue, Mix with `CommonsChunkPlugin`. We also set our index to not cache, but it seems like the async chunks hang on to cached versions.

Comment: No, I still don't know how to solve this problem. I tried to change plugin to WebpackChunkHash as mentioned in this discussion, but it didn't has any effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `webpack.mix.js` change it to this:

```
mix.config.webpackConfig.output = {
    chunkFilename: 'scripts/[name].[chunkhash].js',
    publicPath: '/',
};
```

Refer to [this article](https://survivejs.com/webpack/optimizing/adding-hashes-to-filenames/) for more information.

Comment: Final solution was to delete all plugins that works with chunks and use config from above.

Comment: this solution works fine for me and I don't know why!

Answer (score 0):

Configure webpack.mix.js to version your files

```
let version = 0;

mix.config.webpackConfig.output = {
    chunkFilename: 'v/' + version + '/scripts/[name].js',
    publicPath: '/',
};

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/v/'+version+'/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/v/'+version+'/css');
```